# How do I take pictures of a mat from the top?

Tags: technique, product-photography

My mats are 6x9 feet and I want to take pictures at a perpendicular angle from the top so that it is even. As of now I am taking  pictures from the side.

Here is how I am looking to take the picture:

[image: orthogonal view of the mat from above]

Here is what I'm currently doing, which I don't want:

[image: keystoned image of a mat taken from the side]

Comment: Related: [What is the best techniques to photograph large rugs?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/47551)

Comment: In the first link, the rugs are considerably larger (10m×5m!)

Answer (score 5):

> My mats are 6X9 Feet and i want to take pictures at a perpendicular angle from top so that it is even

The real goal here is to shoot the mat from a direction perpendicular to the plane of the mat, so that any perspective distortion in the image is even in all directions. That doesn't mean that the mat has to be on the floor, though. You can hang your mat on a wall, for example, so that you can hold the camera in a normal shooting position and take the photo you want. If hanging the mat isn't practical, you could build a sloped platform, like a very tilted floor; that would let you take the photo from a ladder, but still avoids the need to be directly above the mat.

Lighting is another thing to consider. The larger the light source (like a big softbox), the less you'll have to worry about shadows cast by folds and wrinkles in the material. On the other hand, if you want to bring out the texture of the mat, direct lighting from the side will help.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. That helps
I will create a slope and take the pictures.